# Instrumentation amplifier and op amp V+ and V- shorted internally

Tags: amplifier, integrated-circuit, analog

I have an INA2126 instrumentation amplifier and an OPA277 operation amplifier. I was trying to check if it is busted or not by using the continuity test of the analog multimeter. I'm  not sure if it's the right thing though. The weird thing was when I placed one probe in V+ and V- on the other probe the multimeter buzzed. Sometimes it does not buzz but the needle will move. Does this mean the IC is busted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bulk of ICs made today have internal ESD protection diodes on any I/O pin, configured like this.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faz8Yn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

During normal operation, the only time these diodes become forward biased is when the pin is exposed to a voltage outside the power rails. Poking around an unpowered chip with a DMM, it's entirely possible to measure a short between the power rails. Reverse the leads and it will appear open. Your test is invalid for determining if the ICs are good.

Answer (score 0):

Pull the datasheets on the amps and check to see if you exceeded the differential input limit. I'm stuck on a cell phone, or else I might do it for you. You'll probably have to check the datasheet on your meter to find what it outputs in continuity mode. You may be fine, maybe not.

With very few (usually troubleshooting) exceptions, there is almost never a great reason to check for continuity on an IC unless you are trying to reverse engineer it. And as you may have guessed, continuity on the inputs of an opamp isn't supposed to happen unless it is badly damaged internally.